# Number that is a certain percent between two other numbers, without subtraction

Tags: algorithms

The formula I'm trying to write is relatively simple. I'm looking for a number that is a certain percent between two numbers, i.e:

6 is 50% between 2 and 10.

8 is 75% between 2 and 10.

Subtracting the two numbers, then multiplying by the percentage, then summing the smaller of the two numbers gets me the correct answer. However, I can't use subtraction because I'm working with coordinates and subtraction has too many quirks.

Is there any other way to achieve this result?

Comment: You can't use subtraction?! Then frankly I think you're screwed.

Comment: If I can respectfully disagree, this can be done without subtraction, just two multiplications (by complementary percentages) and addition of the two products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be numbers (or vectors). If we want to find a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$, so that the ratio of the distance from $a$ to $c$ to the distance from $a$ to $b$ is $t:1$, we use
$$c=(1-t)a+tb.$$
Thus for your $75\%$ example, we have $t=0.75$. If $a=2$ and $b=10$, then
$$c=(0.25)(2)+(0.75)(10).$$

This does not entirely avoid subtraction, since we used subtraction to find $0.25$ from $0.75$, but I hope it uses subtraction to an acceptable degree.

Comment: Thanks, that's impressive. But my problem with subtraction stems from the fact that I can't compare the two coordinates to subtract the lesser from the greater. This method still needs the comparison.

Comment: My answer said nothing about lesser or greater. We do not need to know that. All we need to know is our source point $a$, our target point $b$, and the proportion. If for example you want to know the point $c$ whose distance from $10$ is $25\%$ of its distance from $2$, you can choose $a=10$, $b=2$, $t=0.25$, and you get $(0.75)(10)+(0.25)(2)$.

Comment: (0.25)(10) + (0.75)(2) = 4, not 8. The lesser number has to be multiplied by the lesser point.

Comment: @nathancahill - you multiply the number you want to be closest to by the greater fraction - intuitively the more weight you give to a number the closer you get.  In your comment $4$ is closer to $2$ than it is to $10$ - that depends on the weight $0.75$ being applied to $2$, not on $2$ being less than $10$ (The same works with vectors)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks!